# Adding to sites-availible on Apache

Tags: linux, apache

I'm configuring Apache and the setup documentation has me creating a file in .etc.apache2/sites-availible named after my site (example.com) but doesn't say what type of file this is. I tried to just write it up in TextEdit, but then it saves it as example.com.txt. There is already a default there, but it doesn't seem to have a file type. So how can I may a similar file type to put the virtual host code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension of the file would not matter. In fact, you can just edit the `default` file that is already there.

Apache Documentation just *recommends* you to create a separate file for your domain, sine it is cleaner and easier to maintain.

Once you create that file, and add all the corresponding e.g. vhost configuration, you can run:

```
sudo a2ensite your_file_name
```

to tell apache to use your file from now on.

Answer (score 0):

The filetype:

```
.conf
```

Put in it all the VirtualHost directives for your domain...